# If a monstrous creature is destroyed does it lose monstrous?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a creature that became monstrous, it gets destroyed, and I pull it from my graveyard, will I have to reapply monstrous or does it last until the end of the game?

Answer (score 10):

**A creature that leaves the battlefield stops being monstrous.**

Whenever a creature (or any other object) changes zones for any reason, it becomes a new object. That means it will lose monstrous, among other things.

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.

Also, only *permanents* can be monstrous, and permanents only exist on the battlefield

> 701.31a “Monstrosity N” means “If this permanent isn’t monstrous, put N +1/+1 counters on it and it becomes monstrous.”

> 110.1. A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield. A permanent remains on the battlefield indefinitely. A card or token becomes a permanent as it enters the battlefield and it stops being a permanent as it’s moved to another zone by an effect or rule.